# Replacement for _drush_file_private_path()

Tags: drush

I'm trying to get [File Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_permissions/issues/3079536) working in Drupal 8.9 with Drush 9. The old code calls `_drush_file_private_path()`, which doesn't exist anymore, and `_drush_file_public_path()` is probably a no-go as well.

What is the proper way to do the following in Drush 9?

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Define default paths and variables.
$default = 'sites' . DS . 'default';
$private = $default . DS . 'private';
$files = $default . DS . 'files';
$directories = array();

// Check for Private Files subdirectory.
$private_directory = _drush_file_private_path();
if (empty($private_directory)) {
  $private_directory = $private;
}
$directories[] = $private_directory;

// Check for Public Files subdirectory.
$public_directory = _drush_file_public_path();
if (empty($public_directory)) {
  $public_directory = $files;
}
$directories[] = $public_directory;
```

As an additional note, it would be amazing if a resource existed to see all deprecated/removed functions and their equivalent replacements. I can't even get decent results when using a search engine and the function name.

Comment: When I google those functions together with the word "deprecated" I come to https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/2654/files#diff-c1ffcbd9df5e90cffe2b7be05366d1b6L335-L341. Have you tried `\Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\PrivateStream::basePath()` and `\Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\PublicStream::basePath()` already?

Comment: No there is noch such resource. Simply scan the Drush codebase to look for similar patterns.

Comment: @leymannx Yeah, that works. Including the word "deprecated" when searching seems to improve the results significantly. Thanks. Consider writing an answer.

Comment: It should also be noted that DuckDuckGo doesn't return good search results, but Google does.

Comment: Yep, that's true. I have DuckDuckGo as default search engine but for work-related stuff most of the time I have to search via Google (with a logged in dummy account to have even better results later). I have `g` as keyword in the address bar for Google Search and then only have to type `g` and then press tab and can enter the search query I want to feed to Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `_drush_file_private_path()`
- `_drush_file_public_path()`

in the end were just [wrapper functions](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/2654/files#diff-c1ffcbd9df5e90cffe2b7be05366d1b6L335-L341) of

- `\Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\PrivateStream::basePath()`
- `\Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\PublicStream::basePath()`

And you probably get the same from

- `\Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath('private://')`
- `\Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath('public://')`